# calling a function inside Immediately-Invoked Function from server side - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, server-side, scriptmanager

I've surrounded my script with the following

```
(function ($)
{  
    $(document).ready(function () {....})
    function HandleOpJqUIClientSide(){....}
    .............

})(jQuery);
```

as well as embedding the following in the asp page

```
<script src="~/Scripts/StatsScript.js" type="text/javascript">jQuery.noConflict();</script>
```

I've a function in my script which is being called in server side as following

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "HandleOpJqUIClientSide()", true);
```

it was working properly before handling my script with noconflict (as i need it due to some external plugins that conflicts with my code)

it's now throw

> undefined exception

how can i manipulate the function calling from the server side again

Comment: add ; in HandleOpJqUIClientSide();

Comment: thanks for your reply but I've the same exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to have it like this

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($)
{  
    $(document).ready(function () {....})
    function HandleOpJqUIClientSide(){....}
    .............

})(jQuery);
```

remove `noConflict` from script tag

**Update**

Actually `HandleOpJqUIClientSide` is private within that scope and cannot be accessed directly from outside, we need to have a public accessor for that.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
var noConflict = (function ($){  
    $(document).ready(function () {....})
    return {
         HandleOpJqUIClientSide : function (){....}
    }
    .............

})(jQuery);
```

in server side

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), UniqueID, "noConflict.HandleOpJqUIClientSide()", true);
```

Comment: thx but i've the same exception '0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'HandleOpJqUIClientSide' is undefined'

Comment: it seems that the function became not public in that scope  `(function ($){}(jQuery)`

Comment: @user690069 Oops, I thought of that, but forgot to mention. See my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to do in this way:

```
<script src = "other_lib.js"> </script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script > 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function HandleOpJqUIClientSide() {
        //your $ in the code here will represent JQuery 
    }
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Outside Document ready:

```
var $1=JQuery();
function HandleOpJqUIClientSide() {
    //your $1 in the code here will represent JQuery 
}
```